# onActivityResult not getting called from adapter

Tags: java, android

Been having a problem with getting onActivityResult() in "HomeFragment" to call whenever I finish the "ViewEvent" activity. 
The ViewEvents activity is started from an adapter. The activity starts just fine, but onActivityResult does not get called in home fragment. How can I get this to work?

HomeFragment

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            // Do stuff
            EventListAdapter eventListAdapter = new EventListAdapter(getContext(), 0, events);
            eventListView.setAdapter(eventListAdapter);
}
```

Event List

```
 private Context mContext;

public EventListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<WorkdayEvent> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    setupImageLoader();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list_layout,parent,false);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("EVENT",event);
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ViewEvent.class);
                intent.putExtra("EVENTBUNDLE",bundle);
                Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent,DELETE_EVENT);
        }
        });
    return convertView;
}
```

ViewEvent

```
        final Button deleteEvent = findViewById(R.id.buttonViewEventDelete);
        deleteEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadEvents();
                int index = getEventIndex(event);
                if(index > -1) {
                    workdayEvents.remove(index);
                }
                saveEvents();
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Activity.startActivityForResult` in which case result is not propagated to the fragment.

Pass down fragment to the adapter and use `Fragment.startActivityForResult` to have `onActivityResult` called there.

Comment: How exactly do you pass the fragment to the adapter? Tried getting the fragment from mContext but that doesn't work.